# Class level variable set always nil why?

Tags: ios, swift, getter-setter, userdefaults

I am always getting nil when trying to assign any string to class level variable.

Below is my console output:

> // test = nil 
>       // Demo.test = nil

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Demo.test = "app"
        print("Demo.test = \(Demo.test)")
    }
}

class Demo {

    class var test: String? {
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(test, forKey: "test")
            print("test = \(test)")
        }
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "test")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `test` inside the *setter*, the *getter* is called to get the value of `test`. At this point, the value for "test" is `nil` inside UserDefaults. So instead of storing `test`, you should using `newValue` which is the value that you are about to set to the variable.

```
class Demo {

    class var test: String? {
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "test")
            print("test = \(test)")
        }
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "test")
        }
    }

}
```

---

From the docs,

> If a computed property’s setter does not define a name for the new
>   value to be set, a default name of `newValue` is used.

Check the ComputedProperties section in [Properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html) to understand how getters and setters work.

Comment: I have edit my question as per your suggestion, please check.

Comment: @user3686123 please read the answer carefully. And do not edit the question with the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The code uses `test` to access the value passed to the setter. Using `test` accesses the getter, which returns `nil`.

To use the value provided to the setter use the compiler generated variable `newValue`.

```
class Demo {
    class var test: String? {
        set {
            print("test = \(newValue)")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "test")
        }
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "test")
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can declare the variable name used.

```
class Demo {
    class var test: String? {
        set(newTestValue) {
            print("test = \(newTestValue)")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newTestValue, forKey: "test")
        }
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "test")
        }
    }
}
```

For the first example see [Computed Properties, Shorthand Setter Declaration](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html). For the second one see [Computed Properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html).

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html